# Export Data from Avaya CMS

Tags: avaya

Bit of a long one...

I am trying to reliably export data from Avaya CMS, currently the set up I am using is a Win 2012 Server with Avaya CMS Superviser R18 installed. I have 5 report scripts which I run and they export data to a individual csv files every 3 - 5 seconds. This way was sufficient while we were using CMS Superviser R17 as it would only crash once a day, and when it did, the csv files would stop updating which triggered an email to me once the files had been 120 seconds without updating. This ensured that the reports had very little downtime as I could just quickly restart CMS superviser and the scripts (batch file) rather than having to wait for someone to report that it was no longer updating.

However with CMS SUperviser R18, the software doesn't seem to crash, instead the csv files keep getting updated, but with incorrect data. I am still trying to troubleshoot that issue to find out exactly what is causing it to go out of whack, but while that is ongoing I am also trying to look at alternative solutions.

The reports I am trying to export are custom reports that others in the company have created, and they appear under the designer category

I looked at CLINT but I cannot see the reports I am looking for in there so I ssh'd into the server and using xterm terminal I can view the CMS menus and go through them. In here I noticed that you cannot view any reports under the Integrated tab, nor any reports under the Designer Category of the Real-Time or Historical tabs. I also noticed that there is a "custom reports" section in the menu, although I see no reports under this menu item, just two empty categories (Real-time and Historical)(Pics attached)

[image]

[image]

So my questions are:

1 Do you know if "Custom Reports" is where reports from the designer category should show up? If not, do you know is it possible to access those reports through the ssh menu at all?

2 Has anyone any other ideas as to how to export the data from CMS to a csv file?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Custom Reports" in the *cms* menu you show on the screenshots is different to "Reports" in the Supervisor.

You can read about Custom Reports here (a little old, but still relevant):
https://downloads.avaya.com/elmodocs2/multivantage/215822_3/215822_3_1_CMS_Reports.pdf

If you create reports in the "Custom Reports" subsystem then you can run them using /cms/toolsbin/clint. Note that you must recreate the "Reports" reports in the "Custom Reports" to be able to run them through *clint*.

You can create command files so you can script *clint*, then you just have to run it with a scheduler. You can read about scriping *clint* here:
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=397058

You can also establish a direct connection to the Informix database on CMS but you can not access real-time data there.

Comment: Thank you, so from what I understand, I can recreate the reports I need in the custom reports section which will allow me to then access them in CLINT?